# Understanding reference counting with Cocoa and Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, memory

I'm just beginning to have a look at Objective-C and Cocoa with a view to playing with the iPhone SDK. I'm reasonably comfortable with C's `malloc` and `free` concept, but Cocoa's references counting scheme has me rather confused. I'm told it's very elegant once you understand it, but I'm just not over the hump yet.

How do `release`, `retain` and `autorelease` work and what are the conventions about their use?

(Or failing that, what did you read which helped you get it?)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Let's start with `retain` and `release`; `autorelease` is really just a special case once you understand the basic concepts.

In Cocoa, each object keeps track of how many times it is being referenced (specifically, the `NSObject` base class implements this).  By calling `retain` on an object, you are telling it that you want to up its reference count by one.  By calling `release`, you tell the object you are letting go of it, and its reference count is decremented.  If, after calling `release`, the reference count is now zero, then that object's memory is freed by the system.

The basic way this differs from `malloc` and `free` is that any given object doesn't need to worry about other parts of the system crashing because you've freed memory they were using.  Assuming everyone is playing along and retaining/releasing according to the rules, when one piece of code retains and then releases the object, any other piece of code also referencing the object will be unaffected.

What can sometimes be confusing is knowing the circumstances under which you should call `retain` and `release`.  My general rule of thumb is that if I want to hang on to an object for some length of time (if it's a member variable in a class, for instance), then I need to make sure the object's reference count knows about me.  As described above, an object's reference count is incremented by calling `retain`.  By convention, it is also incremented (set to 1, really) when the object is created with an "init" method.  In either of these cases, it is my responsibility to call `release` on the object when I'm done with it.  If I don't, there will be a memory leak.

Example of object creation:

```
NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] init];  // Ref count is 1
[s retain];                             // Ref count is 2 - silly
                                        //   to do this after init
[s release];                            // Ref count is back to 1
[s release];                            // Ref count is 0, object is freed
```

Now for `autorelease`.  Autorelease is used as a convenient (and sometimes necessary) way to tell the system to free this object up after a little while.  From a plumbing perspective, when `autorelease` is called, the current thread's `NSAutoreleasePool` is alerted of the call.  The `NSAutoreleasePool` now knows that once it gets an opportunity (after the current iteration of the event loop), it can call `release` on the object.  From our perspective as programmers, it takes care of calling `release` for us, so we don't have to (and in fact, we shouldn't).

What's important to note is that (again, by convention) all object creation *class* methods return an autoreleased object.  For example, in the following example, the variable "s" has a reference count of 1, but after the event loop completes, it will be destroyed.

```
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello World"];
```

If you want to hang onto that string, you'd need to call `retain` explicitly, and then explicitly `release` it when you're done.

Consider the following (very contrived) bit of code, and you'll see a situation where `autorelease` is required:

```
- (NSString*)createHelloWorldString
{
    NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];

    // Now what?  We want to return s, but we've upped its reference count.
    // The caller shouldn't be responsible for releasing it, since we're the
    // ones that created it.  If we call release, however, the reference 
    // count will hit zero and bad memory will be returned to the caller.  
    // The answer is to call autorelease before returning the string.  By 
    // explicitly calling autorelease, we pass the responsibility for
    // releasing the string on to the thread's NSAutoreleasePool, which will
    // happen at some later time.  The consequence is that the returned string 
    // will still be valid for the caller of this function.
    return [s autorelease];
}
```

I realize all of this is a bit confusing - at some point, though, it will click.  Here are a few references to get you going:

- [Apple's introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) to memory management.
- [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774086), by Aaron Hillegas - a very well written book with lots of great examples.  It reads like a tutorial.
- If you're truly diving in, you could head to [Big Nerd Ranch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/).  This is a training facility run by Aaron Hillegas - the author of the book mentioned above.  I attended the Intro to Cocoa course there several years ago, and it was a great way to learn.

Comment: You wrote: "By calling autorelease, we temporarily bump the reference count". I think this is wrong; autorelease only marks the object to be released in the future, it doesn't increase the ref count:
http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?AutoRelease

Comment: "Now for autorelease. Autorelease is used as a convenient (and sometimes necessary) way to tell the system to free this object up after a little while."
As a lead-in sentence, this is wrong.  It doesn't tell the system to "free [it] up", it tells it to decrement the retain count.

Comment: Similarly, your last code example releases the NSString one too many times--once in the NSAutorelease pool via autorelease and directly via release :(

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks.  I'm not sure how I missed that with my last edit.

Comment: It's not the init instance method that increases the retain count, but the alloc class method. Apple's rules are linked below, but the summary is "If you alloc, retain, or copy it, it's your job to release it. Otherwise it isn't." -- http://www.stepwise.com/Articles/Technical/2001-03-11.01.html

Apple's docs:
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994

Comment: Your example isn't well chosen. In Core Foundation objects built with a `CFClassCreateInstance` method have a retain count of 1 that has to be released by the calling code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good explanation. Just one thing that is still unclear. If `NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];` returns an autoreleased object (as you write it) why do I have to do a `return [s autorelease];` and set it "autorelease" again and not just `return s`?

Comment: @Stefan: `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"]` will NOT return an autoreleased object.  Whenever `alloc` is called, the reference count is set to 1, and it is the responsibility of that code to make sure it gets released.  The `[NSString stringWithString:]` call, on the other hand, _does_ return an autoreleased object.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You're totally right. I somehow read `stringWithString` from the above example and didn't look closely enough to notice that it is an `initWithString`.

Comment: Fun trivia:  Since the answer uses @"" and NSString, the strings are constant throughout and, thus, the absolute retain count will be both constant and entirely irrelevant.... doesn't make the answer wrong, by any means, just reinforces the fact that absolute retain counts are never really something you should worry about.

Answer (score 10):

If you understand the process of retain/release then there are two golden rules that are "duh" obvious to established Cocoa programmers, but unfortunately are rarely spelled out this clearly for newcomers.

1. If a function which returns an object has `alloc`, `create` or `copy` in its name then the object is yours. You must call `[object release]` when you are finished with it. Or `CFRelease(object)`, if it's a Core-Foundation object.
2. If it does NOT have one of these words in its name then the object belongs to someone else. You must call `[object retain]` if you wish to keep the object after the end of your function.

You would be well served to also follow this convention in functions you create yourself.

(Nitpickers: Yes, there are unfortunately a few API calls that are exceptions to these rules but they are rare).

Comment: This is incomplete and inaccurate.  I continue to fail to understand why people try to repeat the rules rather than simply pointing to the relevant documentation: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Tasks/MemoryManagementRules.html

Comment: The Core Foundation rules in particular are different from those of Cocoa; see http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Comment: I also disagree.  If a function is returning something it doesn't want to own, it should autorelease it.  It is the caller of the functions job to retain it (if desired).  It should have NOTHING to do with the name of any method being invoked.  That is more C Style coding where ownership of objects is unclear.

Comment: Sorry!  I think I was hasty in down-voting.  [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) Your answer nearly quotes the apple doc.

Answer (score 8):

If you're writing code for the desktop and you can target Mac OS X 10.5, you should at least look into using Objective-C garbage collection.  It really will simplify most of your development — that's why Apple put all the effort into creating it in the first place, and making it perform well.

As for the memory management rules when not using GC:

- If you create a new object using `+alloc/+allocWithZone:`, `+new`, `-copy` or `-mutableCopy` or if you `-retain` an object, you are taking ownership of it and must ensure it is sent `-release`.
- If you receive an object in any other way, you are *not* the owner of it and should *not* ensure it is sent `-release`.
- If you want to make sure an object is sent `-release` you can either send that yourself, or you can send the object `-autorelease` and the current *autorelease pool* will send it `-release` (once per received `-autorelease`) when the pool is drained.

Typically `-autorelease` is used as a way of ensuring that objects live for the length of the current event, but are cleaned up afterwards, as there is an autorelease pool that surrounds Cocoa's event processing.  In Cocoa, it is *far* more common to return objects to a caller that are autoreleased than it is to return objets that the caller itself needs to release.

Answer (score 6):

Objective-C uses [Reference Counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), which means each Object has a reference count. When an object is created, it has a reference count of "1". Simply speaking, when an object is referred to (ie, stored somewhere), it gets "retained" which means its reference count is increased by one. When an object is no longer needed, it is "released" which means its reference count is decreased by one.

When an object's reference count is 0, the object is freed. This is basic reference counting.

For some languages, references are automatically increased and decreased, but objective-c is not one of those languages. Thus the programmer is responsible for retaining and releasing.

A typical way to write a method is:

```
id myVar = [someObject someMessage];
.... do something ....;
[myVar release];
return someValue;
```

The problem of needing to remember to release any acquired resources inside of code is both tedious and error-prone. Objective-C introduces another concept aimed at making this much easier: Autorelease Pools. Autorelease pools are special objects that are installed on each thread. They are a fairly simple class, if you look up NSAutoreleasePool.

When an object gets an "autorelease" message sent to it, the object will look for any autorelease pools sitting on the stack for this current thread. It will add the object to the list as an object to send a "release" message to at some point in the future, which is generally when the pool itself is released.

Taking the code above, you can rewrite it to be shorter and easier to read by saying:

```
id myVar = [[someObject someMessage] autorelease];
... do something ...;
return someValue;
```

Because the object is autoreleased, we no longer need to explicitly call "release" on it. This is because we know some autorelease pool will do it for us later.

Hopefully this helps. The Wikipedia article is pretty good about reference counting. More information about [autorelease pools can be found here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Concepts/AutoreleasePools.html). Also note that if you are building for Mac OS X 10.5 and later, you can tell Xcode to build with garbage collection enabled, allowing you to completely ignore retain/release/autorelease.

Comment: This is just wrong.
There is no need to send someObject release or autorlease in either of the examples shown.

Answer (score 6):

Joshua (#6591) - The Garbage collection stuff in Mac OS X 10.5 seems pretty cool, but isn't available for the iPhone (or if you want your app to run on pre-10.5 versions of Mac OS X).

Also, if you're writing a library or something that might be reused, using the GC mode locks anyone using the code into also using the GC mode, so as I understand it, anyone trying to write widely reusable code tends to go for managing memory manually.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to write a hybrid framework that supports both GC and reference counting.

Answer (score 6):

As ever, when people start trying to re-word the reference material they almost invariably get something wrong or provide an incomplete description.

Apple provides a complete description of Cocoa's memory management system in [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011), at the end of which there is a brief but accurate summary of the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Tasks/MemoryManagementRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994).

Comment: Try:
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: And for the summary rules:
http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994

Comment: Actually this is a much better single-page summary: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html

Answer (score 6):

I'll not add to the specific of retain/release other than you might want to think about dropping $50 and getting the Hillegass book, but I would strongly suggest getting into using the Instruments tools very early in the development of your application (even your first one!). To do so, Run->Start with performance tools. I'd start with Leaks which is just one of many of the instruments available but will help to show you when you've forgot to release. It's quit daunting how much information you'll be presented with. But check out this tutorial to get up and going fast:
[COCOA TUTORIAL: FIXING MEMORY LEAKS WITH INSTRUMENTS](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments)

Actually trying to *force* leaks might be a better way of, in turn, learning how to prevent them! Good luck ;)

Answer (score 5):

> [Matt Dillard wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-objective-c#6614):
>
> return [[s autorelease] release];

Autorelease does *not* retain the object. Autorelease simply puts it in queue to be released later. You do not want to have a release statement there.

Answer (score 5):

My usual collection of Cocoa memory management articles:

[cocoa memory management](http://iamleeg.blogspot.com/2008/12/cocoa-memory-management.html)

Answer (score 4):

NilObject's answer is a good start. Here's some supplemental info pertaining to manual memory management (*required on the iPhone*).

If you personally `alloc/init` an object, it comes with a reference count of 1. You are responsible for cleaning up after it when it's no longer needed, either by calling `[foo release]` or `[foo autorelease]`. release cleans it up right away, whereas autorelease adds the object to the autorelease pool, which will automatically release it at a later time.

autorelease is primarily for when you have a method that needs to return the object in question (*so you can't manually release it, else you'll be returning a nil object*) but you don't want to hold on to it, either.

If you acquire an object where you did not call alloc/init to get it -- for example:

```
foo = [NSString stringWithString:@"hello"];
```

but you want to hang on to this object, you need to call [foo retain]. Otherwise, it's possible it will get `autoreleased` and you'll be holding on to a nil reference *(as it would in the above `stringWithString` example*). When you no longer need it, call `[foo release]`.

Answer (score 4):

There's a free screencast available from the iDeveloperTV Network

[Memory Management in Objective-C](http://ideveloper.tv/freevideo/details?index=17012088)

Comment: Unfortunately this link is now a 404.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above give clear restatements of what the documentation says; the problem most new people run into is the undocumented cases.  For example:

- **Autorelease**: docs say it will trigger a release "at some point in the future."  WHEN?!  Basically, you can count on the object being around until you exit your code back into the system event loop.  The system MAY release the object any time after the current event cycle.  (I think Matt said that, earlier.)
- **Static strings**: `NSString *foo = @"bar";` -- do you have to retain or release that?  No.  How about

  ```
  -(void)getBar {
      return @"bar";
  }
  ```

  ...

  ```
  NSString *foo = [self getBar]; // still no need to retain or release
  ```
- **The Creation Rule**: If you created it, you own it, and are expected to release it.

In general, the way new Cocoa programmers get messed up is by not understanding which routines return an object with a `retainCount > 0`.

Here is a snippet from [Very Simple Rules For Memory Management In Cocoa](http://www.stepwise.com/Articles/Technical/2001-03-11.01.html):

> *Retention Count rules*
>
> - Within a given block, the use of -copy, -alloc and -retain should equal the use of -release and -autorelease.
> - Objects created using convenience constructors (e.g. NSString's stringWithString) are considered autoreleased.
> - Implement a -dealloc method to release the instancevariables you own

The 1st bullet says: if you called `alloc` (or `new fooCopy`), you need to call release on that object.

The 2nd bullet says: if you use a convenience constructor *and you need the object to hang around* (as with an image to be drawn later), you need to retain (and then later release) it.

The 3rd should be self-explanatory.

Comment: "Autorelease: docs say it will trigger a release "at some point in the future." WHEN?!"
The docs are clear on that point:
"autorelease just means “send a release message later” (for some definition of later—see “Autorelease Pools”)."
Exacely when depends on the autorelease pool stack...

Comment: ... "The system MAY release the object any time after the current event cycle."
This makes the system sound rather less deterministic than it is...

Comment: ... NSString *foo = [self getBar]; // still no need to retain or release

This is wrong.  Whoever invokes getBar doesn't know the implementation details, so *should* retain/release (typically via accessors) if they want to use it outside of the current scope.

Comment: The "Very Simple Rules For Memory Management In Cocoa" article is in several respects out of date -- in particular "Objects created using convenience constructors (e.g. NSString's stringWithString) are considered autoreleased." is not right -- it is simply "not owned by the recipient".

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good information on cocoadev too:

- [MemoryManagement](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MemoryManagement)
- [RulesOfThumb](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?RulesOfThumb)

Answer (score 0):

As several people mentioned already, Apple's [Intro to Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html) is by far the best place to start.

One useful link I haven't seen mentioned yet is [Practical Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html). You'll find it in the middle of Apple's docs if you read through them, but it's worth direct linking.  It's a brilliant executive summary of the memory management rules with examples and common mistakes (basically what other answers here are trying to explain, but not as well).

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C Memory management**

reference-counting mechanism is implementation of `object ownership` technic for Memory management

**MRC, ARC, GC**

`Manual Reference Counting(MRC)` or `Manual Retain-Release(MRR)` as a developer you  are responsible for counting references on objects manually

[`Automatic Reference Counting(ARC)`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) was introduced in iOS v5.0 and OS X Mountain Lion with xCode v4.2

`Garbage Collection(GC)` was available for Mac OS and was deprecated in OS X Mountain Lion. Must Move to ARC

**Reference count in MRC and ARC**

```
//MRC
NSLog(@"Retain Count: %d", [variable retainCount]);

//ARC
NSLog(@"Retain Count: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef) variable));
```

Every object in heap has an integer value which indicates how many references are pointed out on it. When it equals to 0 object is deallocated **by system**

Lifecycle:

- Allocating object
- Working with Reference count
- Deallocating object. `deinit` is called when `retainCount == 0`

**MRC**

```
A *a1 = [[A alloc] init]; //A has retainCount = 1
    
A *a2 = a1;
[a2 retain]; //A has retainCount = 2

// a1, a2 -> reference on the same object in heap with retainCount = 2
```

Correct way to release an object:

1. `release`. If use only this technic - dangling pointer. Because it still can point on the object in heap and it is possible to send a message. For example A makes +1, B just make a reference(without +1), A makes release -1, counter == 0, object is deallocated but B has a reference to heap
2. `= nil`. If use only this technic - memory leak. `deinit` will not be called. For example when counter == 1 and you make `= nil`. In  any case when you forget release unused object where counter != 0 it causes memory leak

```
A *a = [[A alloc] init]; //++retainCount = 1
[a release]; //--retainCount = 0
a = nil; //guarantees that even somebody else has a reference to the object, and we try to send some message thought variable `a` this message will be just skipped
```

Working with Reference count(Object owner rules):

- (0 -> 1)  `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, `mutableCopy`
- (+1) `retain` You are able to own an object as many times as you need(you can call `retain` several times)
- (-1) `release` If you an owner you must release it. If you release more than retainCount it will be 0
- (-1) `autorelease` Adds an object, which should be released, to `autorelease pool`. This pool will be processed at the **end of RunLoop iteration cycle**(it means when all tasks will be finished on the stack)[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204210/4770877) and after that `release` will be applied for all objects in the pool
- (-1) `@autoreleasepool` Forces process an autorelease pool(release objects) at the **end of block**. It is used when you deal with `autorelease` in a loop and want to clear resources ASAP. If you don't do it your memory footprint will be constantly increasing

For example `autorelease` is helpful in method calls when you allocate a new object there and return it

```
- (B *)foo {
    B *b1 = [[B alloc] init]; //retainCount = 1

    //correct way 
    [b1 autorelease];

    //wrong way is to return b1 without putting it into autorelease beforehand
    return b1; 
}

- (void)testFoo {
    B *b2 = [a foo];
    //if autorelease was not used in foo
    [b2 retain]; //retainCount = 2
    //some logic
    [b2 release]; //retainCount = 1
    
    //Memory Leak
}
```

`@autoreleasepool` example:

```
- (void)testFoo {
    @autoreleasepool {
        for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
            B *b2 = [a foo];
            //process b2
        }
    }
}
```

**ARC**

One of biggest advantage of `ARC` is that it automatically insert `retain`, `release`, `autorelease` under the hood in **Compile Time** and as developer you  should not take care of it anymore

**Enable/Disable ARC**

```
//enable
-fobjc-arc
//disable
-fno-objc-arc
```

Variants from more to less priority

```
//1. local file - most priority
Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Compiler Flags(Select files -> Enter) 

//2. global
Build Settings -> Other C Flags(OTHER_CFLAGS)

//3. global
Build Settings -> Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting(CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC)
```

[image]
[image]

**Check if ARC is enabled/disabled**

`Preprocessor` [`__has_feature`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#has-feature-and-has-extension) function is used

```
__has_feature(objc_arc)
```

Compile time

```
// error if ARC is Off. Force to enable ARC
#if  ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
    #error Please enable ARC for this file
#endif

//or

// error if ARC is On. Force to disable ARC
#if  __has_feature(objc_arc)
    #error Please disable ARC for this file
#endif
```

Runtime

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    // ARC is On
    NSLog(@"ARC on");
#else
    // ARC is Off
    NSLog(@"ARC off");
#endif
```

Reverse engineering(for Objective-C)

```
//ARC is enabled
otool -I -v <binary_path> | grep "<mrc_message>"
//e.g.
otool -I -v "/Users/alex/ARC_experiments.app/ARC_experiments"  | grep "_objc_release"

//result
0x00000001000080e0   748 _objc_release

//<mrc_message>
_objc_retain
_objc_release
_objc_autoreleaseReturnValue
_objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue
_objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
_objc_storeStrong
```

**Tool to Migrate Objective-C MRC to ARC**

ARC generates errors where you should manually remove `retain`, `release`, `autorelease` and others issues

```
Edit -> Convert -> To Objective-C ARC...
```

**New Xcode with MRC**

If you enable MRC you get next errors(warnings)(but the build will be successful)

```
//release/retain/autorelease/retainCount
'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode
ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
```