# how to release controls created by ib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iboutlet

I used IB to created some `UIView` objects and used `IBOutlet` to link to my code.
Some samples below:

```
1.  IBOutlet  UIView *view1;

2.  IBOutlet  UIView *view1;  @property(retain)  UIView *view1;

3.  UIView *view1 ;  @property(retain) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
```

what's the difference ? should I `release` them manually ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove it manually....

your third statement would work correctly... as Xcode identifies nib controls from its property declaration and not from inside class declaration.

(in side class)

```
IBOutlet  UIView *view1;
```

Interface builder probably won't recognize it as IBoutlet as it is declared only inside the class. (class variable are protected)

```
IBOutlet  UIView *view1;  @property(retain)  UIView *view1;
```

Interface builder probably won't recognize it as IBoutlet as it is declared only inside the class. (class variable are protected)

```
3.  UIView *view1 ;  @property(retain) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
```

correct way Interface builder will recognize it. and it will show it when you connect referencing outlet from your Interface builder

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529350/do-you-have-to-release-iboulets-in-dealloc) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to release manually all of the IBOutlets in

`dealloc` and set it nil in `unload`.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can release them in dealloc method manually.

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [view1 release];
  [view2 release];
  [super dealloc];

}
```

Comment: Never call [super dealloc] first. That always goes last. You tear down your subclass's state, *then* let the object be destroyed.