# Do I need to release static uiviews in .xib file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is somewhat an attendant question to [Do I need to release xib resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61838/do-i-need-to-release-xib-resources)

If I have added a static UIView (for example an UILabel that doesn't change) do I need to release it?

**Since I'm not going the edit the UIView I haven't created any connection, @property or @synthesize.**

Do I still need to create this in order to connect it in my IB and release it? That does seem like strange logic. But I want to be certain that this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you needn't release it unless you have a property retain. You send release message to decrement the object count and in your case it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm pretty sure you don't have to release xib resources you don't have an outlet for.
When you create an outlet, it might look like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

The **retain** bit is the important bit in there. That's why you have to release it.
You shouldn't have to for things you don't have an outlet for.