# TTTableViewController is a bit jumpy?

Tags: three20

I'm using the TTTableViewController and datasource and I notice every time a new cell is being loaded it is a little bit sticky. My source code is too long to post so I was wondering if there were any tips or things to look out for to optimize the three20 table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very interesting. I have a tableView that creates many UIImageViews in lazy loaded cells and replacing imageWithContentsOfFile virtually removed a slight pause when the cells were being recreated. Each cell has 1 changing image, and 2-3 images that never change.

According to this thread, imageNamed should not be used: [img_data_lock iphone - imageNamed vs imageWithContentsofFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907780/img-data-lock-iphone-imagenamed-vs-imagewithcontentsoffile), I have not noticed any crashes with imageNamed, can you explain why this is so?