# Objective C - Iphone: Image constant?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, constants

Is it possible to have an image as a constant in Objective C for iPhone development?

Answer (score 2):

Image can't be a constant, however using [UIImage imageNamed:@"image file name"] is using cache so after the first call, this should be very efficient.
However it will take app memory for that, so it use carefully.

Comment: When will this cached image be release ?

Comment: it will not, if you need to release it you should manage it yourself.
look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316236/uiimage-imagenamed-vs-uiimage-imagewithdata