# Why won't this image show up? Using NSData and initWithData

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

```
NSURL* urlEx = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Pacific_Map.png"];
NSData* mapExIMGData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: urlEx];

UIImage* imgEx = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mapExIMGData];

mapImageViewEx.image = imgEx;
```

If I replace mapImageViewEx.image = imgEx; with mapImageViewEx.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pacific_Map.png"]; it works, but I do not want to use imageNamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because imageNamed knows where to scan for the file, but initWithContentsOfURL expects the full path. use

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Pacific_Map" ofType:@"png"];
NSURL* urlEx = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
NSData* mapExIMGData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: urlEx];

UIImage* imgEx = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mapExIMGData];

mapImageViewEx.image = imgEx;
```

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure that's correct? The image still does not show up. I did a quick look over, and I can't find any mistakes..

Comment: NSURL URLWithString should have been fileURLWithPath, i edited the original answer :)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using imageNamed?  Anyway, you could use initWithContentsofPath.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

Tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish.  Good luck,

James

EDIT:  Sorry, I assumed Pacific_Map.png was just a placeholder path.  Like someone else posted, you need to indicate the full path if you're not going to use imageNamed.

Comment: I don't want to cache the image.

Comment: Check this posting out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316236/uiimage-imagenamed-vs-uiimage-imagewithdata  Anyway, imageWithContentsOfFile does not cache images, so that could be viable for you.  Still, depending on what you're doing, caching the image could actually reduce your memory usage...  Explained better in the posting.