# which take less memory, uiimage and image with content of file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, uiimage

I am using HD images and my memory is full after some times, I am update my images with `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];`, is it right in terms of memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` caches the image. Try using `[UIImage imageWithData:]` instead.

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316236/uiimage-imagenamed-vs-uiimage-imagewithdata

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is working.
In our app we compared with another method like

1)

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[
        [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainScreenBackground" ofType:@"png"]]]];
```

taken memory usage 22 mb

2)

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageWithData:
        [NSData ] pathForResource:@"mainScreenBackground" ofType:@"png"]]]];
```

taken memory usage 15mb
thanks alot