# Two iPhone memory management questions

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have two questions.

1) Which of these will release ob?

```
- (void){
  ClassOne *ob = [[ClassOne alloc] init]; // should I use autorelease here?
  self.O = ob;
   [ob release]; // is this correct ??
}
```

or

```
-(void)dealloc{
 [O release]; // is this correct?
}
```

2) There are two classes, `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo`. A method in `ClassTwo` is:

```
- (void) takeParam:(ClassOne *pt) {
  // something going here
}
```

and there is method in a third class

```
- (void) runIt {
   ClassOne *ob = [[ClassOne alloc] init];
   [classTwoOb takeParam:ob];
}
```

Where should I call release for the `ClassOne` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 1 is probably correct.

```
ClassOne *ob = [[ClassOne alloc] init]; // do i should use autorelease here ?
```

When you call `[ClassOne alloc]` you get an object with a retain count of 1 and you are responsible for the release.

```
self.O = ob;
```

Assuming `self.O` is a `retain` property and not an `assign` property, `self.O`/`ob` will have a retain count of 2.

```
[ob release];
```

Now `self.O`/`ob` will have a retain count of 1. This `release` matches up with the `alloc`. The remaining retain count is owned by `self` so you'll have to remember to release `O` when `self` is finished with it.

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [O release]; // is this correct ??
}
```

Good. You remembered to release `O`. Now `O` will be fully released when `self` is dealloced. (Note: you should call `[super dealloc]` at the end of `dealloc`.)

```
- (void) runIt {
   ClassOne *ob = [[ClassOne alloc] init];
   [classTwoOb takeParam:ob];
}
```

You should release `ob` after calling `takeParam:`. Methods are responsible for retaining objects they want to keep. If `takeParam:` stores `ob` on `classTwoOb`, it should be retained before the method returns. If not, it shouldn't.

Use `autorelease` in methods that return objects that they have created. This gives the caller a chance to retain the object if it wants it, or not if doesn't need it for long. The exception to this is methods used to create objects, which should always be called `alloc`*, `new`*, or `*copy*`, and should return the object with a reference count of 1, making the caller responsible for the release.

To really learn Objective-C memory management, I recommend reading the Memory Management Programming Guide, especially the section on [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH).

Answer (score 3):

The `-release` method only reduces the retain count of the object in question. When the retain count reaches zero, the runtime will call `-dealloc`.

If at any time you send an `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain` message you must later call `release` or `autorelease`.

For more details see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-objective-c/6614#6614).