# Objective-C: when does an assigned object get deallocated

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I have a instance method and within this method I do something like this:

```
NSString *peopleString = [peopleList componentsJoinedByString: @", "];
...
UILabel *likeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16.0+6.0f, 4.0f, 252.0f, 12.0f)];
[likeLabel setText:peopleString];
[likeLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]];
[likeRow addSubview:likeLabel];
[likeLabel release];
```

The `componentsJoinedByString` doesn't contain a `new`, `copy` or `alloc`, thus I don't have to release it. What I'm wondering though is, when my peopleString gets deallocated. Might it happen to early? Meaning, before I can set the text in my label. Should I better use a `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[peopleList componentsJoinedByString: @", "]];` and release it at the end of this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `peopleString` it gets reference count of 1. Later, when you tell `likeLabel` to use `peopleString` for its text, the reference count of `peopleString` is incremented by 1. Now the reference count for `peopleString` is 2. When `likeLabel` is released, presumably at the end of the event loop, the reference count of `peopleString` is decremented by 1. But your instance of `peopleString` is also getting its reference count decremented by 1 via the end of the event loop. So `peopleString` now has a reference count of 0 and is removed from memory.

See [#6578](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-objective-c) for a much better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-released objects (like "*peopleString*" in your code) are released by an auto-release pool (*NSAutoreleasePool*), when the "*drain*" method is called.
AppKit creates an auto-released pool on each cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end.
So while you're code is executing (in a method, for instance), the objects won't get deallocated.

Comment: There is a small overhead to using autorelease pools (which can accumulate to become a big overhead), so in general, very loosely, it is better to use alloc/init followed by release. However: I rarely bother.

Comment: Or, you can create other instances of NSAutoreleasePool. That way, objects don't accumulate till the end of the event loop, and you're saving some performance, as all your objects will be deallocated at the same time. : )

Comment: Thanks for the answers/comments Macmade and Paul.