# NSString and UITouch...what in the world is going on?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nslog, uitouch

I have an error with NSString. In one of my .m files I have a member called "conversions" of type NSString and within a method of that class the string is manipulated and added on to and etc. Well, when I try to Log that string in a different method that is later called, for some reason the string is printing as a UITouch object. Specifically, I try to log the string as follows

```
NSLog(@"%@", conversions);
```

and in my console it prints

```
<UITouch 0x131700> phase: Ended tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x136470; frame = (0 0: 320 480) opaque = NO.....(and more property type stuff)
```

Why has my NSString turned into what looks like a UITouch object? What is going on?

Comment: Please show the output using NSLog(@"[%@]". conversions);  It might be that the output you are seeing is the NSString text

Comment: The output is the same except there are brackets at the beginning and at the end: [UITouch 0x131700> phase....]

Comment: you have an over release problem, like the answer below says...The memory that the NSString points to is being reclaimed and reused (this time by some UITouch object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A likely cause for problems like these is that "conversions" got released too early, thus got deallocated and you were still holding a reference to that memory location. Then another object got allocated at this location.

To debug this, set NSZombieEnabled. It doesn't deallocate objects but replaces them with "zombies". See for example the following link:

http://www.tomwhitson.co.uk/blog/2009/04/debugging-with-nszombiesenabled/

Comment: This seems to be the problem. Why would it have been released too early and how do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Well obviously you either called [conversions release] or [conversions autorelease] too often or you called [conversions retain] to few :-) Without context I can't tell. But have a look at this:

http://blog.mikeweller.com/2009/07/retain-and-release-rules-in-objective-c.html

Comment: Another good link is this one here on Stack Overflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-objective-c

Comment: I never called conversions release or autorelease except for a release call in the dealloc method. I'm not familiar with retain. When declaring the string in the .h file, I make it a property with a nonatomic, retain property. Is this not enough?

Comment: Then you need to use property assignment: `self.conversions = ...`