# Using properties in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, oop, class

I understand what read and write do when used as a properties but I'm confused with the rest.

- What is nonatomic and what is it used for?
- What is retain and what is it used for?
- Why is copy used? Wouldn't it be equivalent to "read" since read also returns the value of the variables?
- What is assign used for? Wouldn't it be equivalent to "write" since both set copies of the variable?
- Properties basically create getter and setter functions. Do they however create actual functions or do I just access the variable as in `[class variable]`? (instead of `[class getVariable]` or `[class setVariable:int variable]`. If I am just directly accessing the variable isn't this the equivalent of making the variable public?

Comment: All this is explained in the Objective-C programming Guide. And the individual questions have been answered many times on this site already. You'd be better off reading the documentation rather than asking here in the first instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know which flags are alternatives to each other:

- nonatomic is in a group by itself
- retain, copy, assign
- readonly, readwrite

By default, getters and setters are thread-safe which also incurs a performance penalty. nonatomic tells the compiler to not worry about thread-safety considerations when writing getters and setters for that property. It will be faster, and should be preferred if you will only access that property from a given thread, usually the main thread.

assign tells the compiler to generate a setter that does not retain the new value. You should use it for primitive properties (`int`, `BOOL`, etc). copy creates a new copy of the object when it is assigned. retain calls `[newValue retain]` on the new value of the object and `[oldValue release]` on the old value of the object in the setter.

For completeness, readonly tells the compiler to only generate a getter, not a setter, whereas readwrite generates both.

When you access the variable using `[class variable]`, you *are* calling a function with the same name as the property. This lets you implement the getter or setter at a future point with your own implementation, without having to modify your code in numerous other places.

Answer (score 1):

There's 3 different "sets" of attributes you can add to properties:

1. `nonatomic` vs default (I.e. not specifying `nonatomic`)

   This determines whether or not generated accessors include using a mutex to synchronise calls.
2. `retain` vs `assign` vs `copy`

   This determines the semantics for what it means to *set* the property. `retain` means that the object passed in is retained, i.e. if you pass in an object then it's that *exact* object that is set and it's retained (it's retain count is incremented). `copy` means that a copy of the object is made and that is kept. `assign` means that it's that exact object that is set, but it's not retained.
3. `readonly` vs `readwrite`

   This determines whether or not a getter (`readonly`), or a getter and a setter (`read write`) are available (and synthesised during an `@synthesize`).

If you are unfamiliar with any parts of these different sets of attributes then I suggest reading about them individually. For instance the `retain` vs `assign` vs `copy` is all about memory management. If you are unsure what each one is, why they're different and what it means when programming then please go and read about memory management in Objective-C (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-and-objective-c)). If you are unsure what it means for calls to the accessors being synchronised as per `nonatomic` vs `atomic` then you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties).

Comment: The atomic attribute doesn't exist, only nonatomic. Properties are atomic by default.

Comment: Fair point - just more succinct than `nonatomic` vs not-`nonatomic`! You're right though.