# how to use nsdate string objec for later use?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm so fedup with `NSDate` string object. 
     currently I am generating an unique id on the bases of `NSDate` as follows:

```
NSDate *current_date = [[NSDate date]retain];
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HHmmssddMMYY"];
NSString *unique_id=[df stringFromDate:current_date];
NSString  *   current_Test_id=[NSString stringWithString:unique_id];
NSLog(@"current_test_idString %@",current_Test_id);
```

The code above is generating unique id and prints successfully but if I am printing or accessing `currtent_Test_id` in another `IBAction` method then app crashes.

Comment: is current_Test_id an ivar and are you releasing current_date anywhere?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: its nsstring. and i'm not releasing current_date anyware?

Comment: sorry my mistake.... please show the error log.

Comment: if current_test_id is global, so plz tell me is it instance variable of your class ?

Comment: yaa.. its instance variable...

Comment: my answer will work for you, use this method.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stringWithString will create an autorelease string, modify your code as

```
NSString  *   current_Test_id = [[NSString stringWithString:unique_id]retain];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Method

```
 - (NSString *)stringDateFromDate: (NSDate *) date{

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HHmmssddMMYY"]; 
    NSString *current_Test_id=[NSString stringWithString:[df stringFromDate:date]];
    [df release];
    NSLog(@"current_tst_id %@",current_Test_id);

    return current_Test_id;

}
```

Call Method Like that

```
NSString  *current_tst_id = [self stringDateFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: please check it in instrument, I dont think that there is memory leak

Comment: Now its fine, your initial answer did not contain `[df release]`. You corrected it 8 mins ago... :)

Comment: if it was missing then you must have to edit it and change the code, as you can.

Comment: yes thats why, i gave you time to check and correct. I did not use my downvote. However Good Work. But his problem was something else, he wanted to set the id to ivar...and he missed to retain it.

Answer (score 0):

an NSString (or any object, for that matter) created with a class method, and not an init method, will be autoreleased. This means on the next iteration of the event loop, `current_Test_id` is released, and now you have a pointer to a dead object.

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-and-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

As `current_Test_id` is instance method.

in the init (in case of mac os) or viewDidLoad (for ios) alloc+init it.

and then assign :

```
current_Test_id=[NSString stringWithString:unique_id]; //it will be in autorelease mode.
```

or

```
current_Test_id=[[NSString stringWithString:unique_id]retain];
```