# how to mange memory with properties

Tags: ios, memory-management, dealloc, alloc

I am new to iOS so trying to understand memory management.

I have a .h File which contains a property and i want to use that var in some function.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

then in my .m File i have some function x.

```
-(void) x
{
     // How to allocate memory to the property variable  ??

     _myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
OR
     myArray= [[NSMutableAraay alloc]init]


 // what is the utility of "_" here ?
}
```

and how to manage memory in this case as we have **already used keyword** `Retain` in .h file and also allocated memory in func x then how to do memory management.

In dealloc method

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[myArray release];
OR
[_myArray release];
// same here whats the difference B/W 2.?
[super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@property` and `@synthesize` creates two methods, called accessors, that set and get a backing instance variable. The accessors are called either through normal method calls or dot notation (`self.propertyname`). The accessors offer a place to perform memory management or other tasks, which can be controlled to an extent in `@synthesized` accessors through the use of `nonatomic`/`copy`/etc. You can still directly access the instance variable a property masks by using the instance variable's name instead of `self.propertyName`. By default, the instance variable's name is the property's name preceded by an underscore. The underscore prevents people from accidentally directly accessing the instance variable when they don't mean to and can prevent namespace collisions. You can also implement your own accessors.

```
self.myArray //goes through the setter/getter of the property
_myArray     //directly accesses backing instance variable while ignoring accessors
myArray      //incorrect
```

Note that the name of the backing instance variable can be changed using `@synthesize myPropertyName = myCoolName`.

In terms of usage, in most cases you would use `self.thing`. The exception would be custom setters/getters (ex. `return _thing`) and `dealloc` where you would use `[_thing release]` to counter the `retain` that was sent to the object when it passed through the `retain`-style setter. The reason for not calling the accessor within the accessor should be obvious. We don't use the accessor in `dealloc` to prevent unwanted effects.

EDIT: Here's some nice resources to help you better understand manual reference counting.

1. [Understanding reference counting with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-and-objective-c)
2. [Memory Management Programming Guide (from Apple)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Also, if you want to develop for iOS consider using ARC. ARC stands for Automatic Reference Counting. Unlike MRC (Manual Reference Counting) where you explicitly add `retain` and `release` calls to your code, ARC conservatively handles reference counting for you, retaining and releasing objects as it sees fit. You can read about ARC below.

3. [Transitioning to ARC (from Apple)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)

Comment: well thanks a lot for enriching me, what act using alloc with properties as i mentioned in above code and how to dealloc .. It will be very great and kind of you to have more enlightenment on this ..

Comment: @VinayChopra If I understand you correctly you want me to explain how `alloc` and `dealloc` work with properties more clearly? Normally, you should use `self.myArray` most of the time, including when using `alloc`, and `_myArray` in `dealloc`. If you aren't using custom getters/setters then the main function of accessors is memory management, locking code and KVO compliance. `self.myArray = ...` is the same as `[self setMyArray: ...]` while `_myArray` just directly changes the value. If you were just thanking me, then sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: that was awesome from your side dude, One last Query if you dnt Mind , if i allocate memory in any Func then where to release it ?? as you already cleared the Doubt of Property :) . Just thinking act how to manage memory with Functions (well i know how to do with (id)init -Just make a temp Var and do self.myVar= TempVar ; & release the TempVar.) Just looking for Functions also .I know i am becoming greedy to get knowledge from you but it will be great if you can answer this also.

Comment: @VinayChopra I'll edit my post and add a link to a good answer that talks about reference counting and memory management in depth. In general, you retain an object (or call a method that returns an object that has already has retain called on it for you) and this asserts ownership of it by adding one to its `retain count`. The object will not be deallocated as long as the `retain count` is above zero. As soon as you are done with the object, you send it `release` to subtract one from its `retain count` and balance things out. In functions, you generally send release at the end of the function.

Comment: that will be so nice of you :)