# CCSprite overlaps one over another

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

     _nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"arrow.png"]retain];
     _nextProjectile.position = imgArrow.position;

        [imgArrow runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                            [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                            [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishShoot)],
                            nil]];
    //Some code 

    }

- (void)finishShoot {

    // Ok to add now - we've finished rotation!

    [self addChild:_nextProjectile];
    [_projectiles addObject:_nextProjectile];

    // Release
    [_nextProjectile release];
    _nextProjectile = nil;
}
```

When I click on bow twice my arrow overlaps one over another.

any help ?![image]

Comment: i read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-and-objective-c  as reference.still i'm not able to resolve my problem.

Comment: There is only one arrow in my project having name _nextProjectile.
and i'm releasing it using finishShoot method in runAction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your previous arrow before releasing next arrow with touch. I think you are making a shooting game where an arrow is released as the screen is touched. I would recommend removing the last arrow when it's action is complete

Comment: It is not removed from the scene by just releasing it. You need to add [self removeChild: _nextProjectile cleanUp:YES];

Comment: i wrote [self removeChild:_nextProjectile cleanup:YES];  after
[imgArrow runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                        [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                        [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishShoot)],
                        nil]];

still it didn't work :(

Comment: i'm adding arrow in finishShoot method because i want to add only that arrow which shoots the projectile.not each of them..

Comment: Your code is confusing. Elaborate what exactly you require here

Comment: for(CCSprite *arrow in _projectiles){
        [self removeChild:arrow cleanup:YES];

    }
Add this code at the start of your touch method. It will remove all the existing arrows and there will be only one when you add

Comment: When arrow fires from bow it will collide from projectiles which comes randomly from scene.If arrow collide from projectile it should remove from screen.or if it didn't collide it also should remove when it goes off screen..
here,if i press once on my bow it will fire and remove from screen very nicely but when i click twice on bow once my arrow is fire and then it appears on my bow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28665/discussion-between-v-d-and-sahil-arora)

Comment: Still confusing.. Try the code above and let me know if it suits your need. Else we will do something else (y)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, in it before adding we have removed arrow, (fix syntactical error if there any)

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 [self removeChild:[self childWithTag:101]];
 _nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"arrow.png"]retain];
 _nextProjectile.tag = 101;
 _nextProjectile.position = imgArrow.position;

    [imgArrow runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                        [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                        [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishShoot)],
                        nil]];
//Some code 

}
```

Comment: i wrote [self removeChild:_nextProjectile cleanup:YES];
        [self addChild:_nextProjectile];
        [self removeChildByTag:101 cleanup:YES];
        _nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"arrow.png"]retain];
        _nextProjectile.tag = 101;
        _nextProjectile.position = imgArrow.position;

but still result is same.

Comment: because i already assign tag to _nextProjectile..
i have remove another tag..now when i fire arrow for 1st time it will move into proper direction..but it didn't move for 2nd time.

Comment: You mean child is not getting removed, make sure you have not added is from some where else then, like in touches begun or move or any method that get called in chain.

Comment: yes,,i have added in my finishShoot method...so,i have removed it from that method but still result is same.