# How Memory allocated without calling alloc - NSArray,NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have two viewcontroller:

`viewcontroller1` - Has Property `NSArray` `array1` and in `viewDidLoad` I am assigning
`self.array1 = @[@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d"];`

Question 1 :
How without coding alloc, this `array1` allocated memory and storing values?

Question 2 :
Now I have `viewcontroller2` - Has Property `NSArray` `array2`

Using `prepareForSeque` method, I am assigning `array1` value to `array2`,

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setArray2:self.array1];
```

In the `viewcontroller2` - `viewDidLoad` if I log `array2` I am getting the value. Where got `array2` memory allocated?

Comment: Who says that `@[@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d"]` *doesn't* call `alloc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. its called syntactic sugar, the compiler allocates the needed memory.
2. array2 is just a pointer. you assign to it the memory address of the allocated memory of array1

you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578/understanding-reference-counting-with-cocoa-and-objective-c) for good examples

Comment: Hi Dima ,Thanks for the response . Question1 - Got it!  Question2 - My understanding reference count of array1 is increased to 2 . The other thing when i dealloc/release array1,then array2 wont have any value. .Please correct me .

Comment: when you release the reference count decreases to 1, so the object is still in the memory. only when you release it again, it will be deleted

Comment: got doubt here - Ok now the RC for array1 is 2 .When i do dellac the RC becomes 0 not 1 .please correct me .

Comment: Great answer. Just wanted to add that the "syntactic sugar" in this case can be referred to as an NSArray literal. It's a shorthand way of allocating and initializing your instance of NSArray.